# TortoiseHG Update Remote Repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have recently added several projects to an existing repository on my local dev box. I periodically synchronize the local repository to a network drive repository. However, the new projects do not automatically show up on the network repo---only the ones that were there when I performed the initial clone.

How do I get the new projects into my network repo?

Comment: I assume you needed to run update at the remote repos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the 'hg push' command to push changesets from local to remote and use 'hg pull' to pull changesets from remote to local.

Moving the changesets over is sufficient to get the contents there, but if you want to see them in the working directory you `hg update`.

Also it sounds like you have multiple projects in a single repo.  That's the normal setup in subversion, but in Mercurial or git you want separate repositories per project.  It's better that way because all changesets/commits span the entire repo and it's not possible to `hg update` or `hg clone` only a portion of the repo like it is with svn.

Comment: You question shows you're confused.  "update" doesn't do any data transfer.  push/pull move data to/from machine.  update/commit move data between your local repository `.hg/...` and your working directory.  So no, you can't `update` over HTTP, but you can push/pull over HTTP.

Comment: Oh I know the difference. Pulling&pushing works well, but having to SSH into the remote server each time is a pain, and using the `changegroup` hook removes the freedom to run `hg update` whenever one wants, so was looking for a non-SSH-terminal way to update the repo working directory.

Comment: You could do it in a single line `ssh you@host hg --repo /server/side/path/to/repo hg update`.  It's no different than sshing in, but at least you can make it a local alias and call it `remoteup` or something.